# Binning Data Using Numpy To Simplify Linear Regression

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, keras, conv-neural-network

I have training data in the form of images taken by a `PiCamera` from an RaspberryPi RC car while I drive it in between two lane lines.

Each image is labelled with Left and Right motor controls.  I've plotted them in the below graph.

I am using `ConvNets` to do the regression with `Keras` and `TensorFlow` as backend.

It's clearly visible that regression can be much simpler if I am able to remove the training samples which are to the left of the visible regression.

The code for loading the images and labels is very simple and is below:

```
filenames = glob.glob("../data/*.jpg")

labels = []

images = []

for filename in filenames:
    # Timestamp-LeftMotorControl-RightMotorControl.jpg

    filename = filename.replace('.jpg', '')

    parts = filename.split('-')

    if float(parts[1]) == 0. or float(parts[2]) == 0.:
        continue

    images.append(filename)

    labels.append([float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])])
```

[image]

Firstly is there a good approach for removing data which is out of bounds of the visible regression from the training samples?

Also, I have a different approach in mind which is to create `100` data bins with edges of `0` to `1`, then take 50 samples from each bin such that my data is balanced.

Is there a `numpy` way to put the data into bins so that I don't need to do that with some custom function?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the first question:

1. Do the linear regression fit on the whole dataset
2. Remove the points with the largest residuals
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until all residuals are comfortably small

Comment: In classification we use validation data for testing (rather than the test data) to avoid over-fitting to the test data.  Wouldn't this approach cause over-fitting to the test set?  Can it generalize well to completely unseen images?

Comment: If I've understood correctly, by residual you mean the variance between actual and predicted.  Correct? Hence my confusion about generalization.

Comment: @SamHammamy If the OP has a reason to believe that there is a causal linear relationship between the two variables, than I would not worry about overfitting.

Comment: My apologies, I'm the OP and I'm still learning the ins and outs of ML.

Comment: can a `numpy.histogram2d` be useful here?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I did not realize :) So, if you _believe_ there is always a visible straight line in your data, you can find it using the proposed approach.